# Remove Old Git Repo (local) Unwittingly Init'ed

Tags: git, macos, github

A few months back, when I was first introduced to Git, it seems I had created a repo in my Users/username folder (Mac). I have no idea wether or not I have commited anything, but everything I've done since then is waiting to be 'added'.

The branch is named 'bounce' not sure if I gave it this name or not.

I tried to just delete the .git folder, but this adds all the untracked/uncommitted files/branches etc. to every repo in the sub folders. (See example at bottom).

I was thinking I could just add and commit ALLLLL the files and get rid of it, but when I run git add ., I get :

> warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .meteor/packages/less/.1.0.14.3q4gos++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLess.os/npm/compileLess/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek/lib/escape.js.
>
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .meteor/packages/less/.1.0.14.3q4gos++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLess.os/npm/compileLess/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek/lib/index.js.
>
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .meteor/packages/less/.1.0.14.3q4gos++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLess.os/npm/compileLess/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek/test/escaper.js.
>
> The file will have its original line endings in your working directory.
>   warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in .meteor/packages/less/.1.0.14.3q4gos++os+web.browser+web.cordova/plugin.compileLess.os/npm/compileLess/node_modules/less/node_modules/request/node_modules/hawk/node_modules/hoek/test/index.js.
>   ...

I don't use meteor but I don't want to screw anything up or reset everything to where it was 7 months ago! What can I do?

Example:

In Users/username:`git status`
lists ~100 files/directories

cd into a project Users/username/Documents/project: `git status`
nothing to commit

delete Users/username/.git

Back in User/username: `git status`
not a repo

cd into a project Users/username/Documents/project: 
    `git status`

lists the same ~100 files/directories

Comment: "I tried to just delete the .git folder, but this adds all the untracked/uncommitted files/branches etc. to every repo in the sub folders." This is very confusing. Could you please expand on it?

Comment: Oops sorry, check out the example I added.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have a git repository inside other git repository.

You can checkout what is the root folder of your git repository using this command:

```
git rev-parse --show-toplevel
```

Once you have this root you can know where all those files are coming from.

In your case looks like the root folder is:

```
Users/username/Documents/project
```

Comment: You are right, I have nested repos, but I already knew where the root repo was, I just want to know how to get rid of it with out losing anything.